# AppwriteException: Missing required parameter: "collectionId"

Tags: reactjs, vite, appwrite

i got error after debloy my app with netlify *AppwriteException: Missing required parameter: "collectionId"* but it work when i in a dev version

i sure that it work fine with my devlopment version here is a link of the rebo [snapgram](https://github.com/mohamed-abd-elkahlk/snapgram)  i got the error from /src/lip/appwrite/api.ts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error may occur if you have not configured your environment with all the necessary environment variables as shown here:
[image: GitHub code]

Please ensure that your environment on Netlify isn't missing a collection ID.